# Why is VSCode running the wrong jupyter server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

macOS v. 11.2.3.
2 versions of python installed

```sh
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

I created a virtual environment (`venv`) to work with a jupyter notebook, but every time I open a document in a VSCode, I see 2 servers start up at the same time and the last one that is selected is not the one that is in the virtual environment:
[image]
Moreover, every time I open a document, I have several files in the trash with something like this name:

```
chunks-3a679475-8ceb-44eb-9ac3-fcefe0595bc1.ipynb
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS Code, it is normal that the python environments of the two are different. The python kernel used by Jupyter Notebook can be independent of the python environment selected in the lower left corner of VS Code, and usually it is the python environment used by VS Code by default. If the python extension has not been loaded yet, Jupyter uses the last python environment by default.

Please click on the location of the python kernel displayed on the upper right of Jupyter, and select the one you need from the expanded options. In addition, please try to reload VS Code.

[image]

Reference: [Working with Jupyter Notebooks in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support).

Comment: This does not work. When I select the kernel at the top right, I see that there are 2 different versions in my virtual environment. every time i choose 3.9, but every new file by default starts with version 3.8 and there are no dependencies.

Comment: @nosheyakku -Have you set the default path used by the relevant Jupyter kernel? Please try to reinstall the "Jupyter" extension and the "Python" extension.

Comment: Where can I select the default kernel?    Yes, I have reinstalled everything.

Comment: @nosheyakku -What extensions did you use in VS Code? It is recommended that you create a new [virtual environment in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments) and check whether it can be activated automatically. If it still cannot use the virtual environment automatically, please select it manually.